# Transferir dados do SQL Server para SQLite com Android

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite

Eu tenho um software que está conectado a uma base de dados SQL Server, mas agora estou a fazer o software em Android utilizando SQLite.

Eu preciso transferir a base de dados do SQL Server (com os dados) para o meu SQLite.

Backup funciona? Mesmo com as views que tenho no SQL Server? Qual é a maneira que eu posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você utiliza o `SQL Studio` é só clicar com o botão direito em cima da base que deseja copiar os dados se selecionar `Tasks > Generate Scripts...`. Preencha as informações até a tela `Set Scripting Options` e clique em `Advanced`. Altere a opção `Types of data to script` para `Data only` (Você precisará criar as tabelas com a mesma estrutura no `SQLite`). Preencha o restante das opções nas demais telas e o `script` será criado. Então você só precisa executá-lo no `SQLite`.

[image: Opções]

[image: Avançadas]